# I don't understand what's happening with my displacement

Tags: rendering, node-editor, displacement

for some reason my displacement bumps up but does not bump down. I want a deep shadow on my wall but the render preview is different to the output. Can somebody help me understand what's going on?

The second to last image is the result I want, the last image is the result I get.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In second to last image you have turned off visibility for 2 planes, one light and one more mesh, when you render the image all of those are visible in final render. To disable them simply click on camera icon next to name of the mesh in outliner.